# Javascript link - trying to set element value - weird behavior chrome & android

Tags: javascript, android, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I encountered a weird issue while developing an Hybrid app in Android and actually managed to reproduce it in Chrome.

**The base idea is an HTML page with an input field, and trying to set the value using JS injection:**

```
javascript:document.getElementById('intest').value = '1111';
```

**If open the javascript link, the JS command instead of setting the text input field - the entire pages is replaced with the value you entered.**

This is the HTML I'm using for demo:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>&lt;input id=&#39;intest&#39; type=&#39;text&#39; /&gt;</p>
<input id='intest' type='text' />
<br/>
<h3>JS Command</h3>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('intest').value = '1111';">javascript:document.getElementById('intest').value = '1111';</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If you enter the same command in the console it will set the value of the input field as expected.

In Android the behavior is the same when using webview.loadURL('javascript:....');

Any ideas why is this happening?

P.S. I created a simple html page to play with:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/453866/injectiontest.html

Update, this also is the case in IExplorer and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It's very odd, even when you inspect the page after clicking the anchor tag you can still see the markup.  I found if you add a `return false;` after you change the value it works as intended.  I tested on chrome, not on Android.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('intest').value = '1111'; return false;">javascript:document.getElementById('intest').value = '1111'; return false;</a>
```

Comment: Nice find with the "return false;", do yo have an explanation why would this change something?

Comment: It's a way to prevent the default browser behavior, like `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: So, I'm guessing it's a bug since I can't imagine the "default" desired behavior here.

Comment: I think it's because you have it in the href attribute, so it's hard for chrome to fully understand where you're sending the user.  Try it in an onclick attribute instead of href without the return false.  I'm guessing that will work too.

Comment: I actually started by pasting the JS command into the browser input line, this is similar to the effect of the loadURL command in android - code injection.
onClick is an internal page JS and doesn't go through the browser URL logic - so it will work.

Comment: BTW another thing that works, is injecting a JS function and then calling it.